# Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in

Tags: php, api, soap, wsdl

I am having a problem with PHP at the moment, I am getting this error,

Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string the error occurs when I run this portion of code in my site,

```
<?php
//Setup
$wsdl='https://api.netbiter.net/operation/v1/soap?wsdl';
$client=new SoapClient ($wsdl);
$accessKey='042B79FC23AB0925D4D20FBB8EE42B98';  //Replace by your access key
$systemId='003011FB506F'; //Replace by your system id
$parameterId='17379.0.44535'; //Replace by your data logging id
$limitRows='24'; //How many hour data logging
$sortOrder='desc'; //Order of the response list
$startDate='2013-12-04T03:00:00Z'; //The UTC start date and time limit for the list
$endDate='2013-12-05T03:00:00Z'; //The UTC end date and time limit for the list
?>

<?php
function handleArgosException(Exception $fault)
{
   echo "Error: ";
   echo "Message: {$fault->faultstring} ";
   if (isset($fault->detail->ForbiddenException))
   {
      echo "Forbidden exception: Code {$fault->detail->ForbiddenException->code}";
   }
   else if (isset($fault->detail->LimitException))
   {
      echo "Limit exception: Code {$fault->detail->LimitException->code}";
   }
   else if (isset($fault->detail->GeneralException))
   {
      echo "General exception: Code {$fault->detail->GeneralException->code}";
   }
}
?>

<?php
echo "<h1>Test Data Logging</h1>";
$param=array ('accessKey'=>$accessKey, 'systemId'=>$systemId, 'parameterId'=>$parameterId,
              'limitRows'=>$limitRows, 'sortOrder'=>$sortOrder, 'startDate'=>$startDate,
              'endDate'=>$endDate);

try
{
   $resSystems = $client->getSystemHourAggregatedLoggedValues($param);
}
catch (SoapFault $fault)
{
   handleArgosException($fault);
}

echo "<h2>Example code</h2>";
foreach($resSystems->HourAggregatedLogParameters as $label => $value)
{
   echo "System $label : $value<br />";
}
?>
```

The line in which the error is occuring is this one,

```
echo "System $label : $value<br />";
```

I don't really now what this problem is, so any help would be great.

Comment: Where do those functions come from? Like getSystemHourAggregatedLoggedValues I don't see that as a class member in the PHP doc

Comment: The function come from webservices(.wsdl). The wsdl link at top one. It is SOAP API webservices.

Comment: https://api.netbiter.net/operation/v1/soap?wsdl

Comment: if you var_dump($resSystems->HourAggregatedLogParamters) what does it say about the object? It seems apparent that you're getting an object that doesn't have __toString() available to use when you go to cast to string via echo

Comment: i change this one.it is correct?
foreach(var_dump($resSystems->HourAggregatedLogParameters) as $label => $value)

Comment: I just wanna see var_dump($resSystems->HourAggregatedLogParameters) before the foreach loop.

Comment: i got the value.but how can i put the variable inside foreach loop?

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/h7wvufv4t/

Comment: the error is for 'foreach' statement.

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite explanatory itself. Its saying that you have a `stdObject` and php does not know how to print that.

Since you have not given any error trace, if you are sure that the error generates from this line
`echo "System $label : $value<br />";`, then what it means is that, the value of `$label` or `$value` is not a normal data type. Its an object of an `un-named` class which is probably generated on-the-fly.

Since a class, this object contains fields which you can print. Or you can define a `toString()` method for this class so that the php can use this method to print your object.

But most likely you are interested in the `fields` of this object. So you can either do **`var_dump($label)`** or **`print_r($label)`** to see what fields are contained in this object. Then you can easily extract those fields like this: `echo $label->field1;`